# UISwipeGestureRecognizer for UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView in which each has a custom UITableViewCell. Inside each of this cell it has a UITextView. I would like to wire each of this UITextView to an event using UISwipeGestureRecognizer when the UITextView is tapped once. How do I do this?

Comment: Wouldn't tap indicate an intention to edit?

Comment: I would like to change that to do something else, this is a non-editable UITextView, I think I forgot to mention that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you really have to do is adopt the UITextView delegate protocol.  Make sure your UITextView instances are editable, then the following method will let you do what you need

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    // call whatever methods you want from here, including the method linked in your gesture recognizer;
    return NO; // this makes sure you don't edit anything, if that is the case you want
}
```

You should be able to do whatever you want from in there since that line gets called every time you tap an editable textView.  If you need to access information about the cell it is in, you can find it through calling superviews.  For example, if you embedded you textView in the contentView of the cell, `textView.superview.superview` will return the cell it is in.  The first superview call returns the contentView while the second gives you the cell.  Calling another superview would give you the tableView.  I hope that helps.

EDIT: getting the index path is pretty simple if you can find the cell the textView is embedded in.  Assuming you have the textView as a subview of the cell's contentView, this is how you would get the index path.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = textView.superview.superview;
// you will get warnings on that.  because you're calling superview, it expects it to be
// a UIView instance, but if you call NSLog(@"%@", textView.superview.superview), it will
// return UITableViewCell, so you can ignore the warning.  anyway, assuming you have a 
// reference to your tableView, you find the index path with the next line
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [myTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
// then call the didSelect method
[self tableView:myTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

If you embed your textView in something other than the contentView, this won't work, you'll just have to add or subtract superview calls in an NSLog statement until you find the cell.  But that should do it for you

Comment: this is actually a non-editable UITextView, it's used to show text like a UILabel... so when you say make sure the UITextView instances are editable...what do you mean by that? You mean making uses to be able to type words into it? As that's not what I want

Comment: If you set `textView.editable = YES;` and use the method I have above, it will not edit the textView.  Returning NO in that method tell the app to stop before letting the user add or modify any text, so it acts just like it's non-editable an no text will ever be added

Comment: ok, so I first need to set the delegate of my UITextView to self, do I do this at cellAtRowForIndexPath?

Comment: Yup.  Wherever you create the textView, set its delegate to self and you're good.  Just make sure that you have <UITextViewDelegate> declared in your header file as well.  Then you should be good to go

Comment: One question remain, I want textViewShouldBeginEditing to actually call - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath, is it okay? How would you do that?

Comment: My only issue is that I need the indexPath of where this UITextView is at in order to make it to work

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely possible.  I'm going to edit the original answer for this though because it'll be easier to read (and type)

Comment: no problem.  hopefully that does the trick for you.  i use this in one of my apps, so it should be good

Answer (score 0):

Attach both tap and swipe recognizers to the text view programmatically. Set the state of the swipe recognizer to disabled at start. On tap, enable the swipe recognizer. If taps are to enable/disable the swipe, that should be easy to do as well.